# How to prevent cell turnaround effect?

Tags: ios, tableview, cell

I'm sorry about I can't upload images because of my low reputation point.

(Screenshots)

http://twitter.com/hseongeon/status/410214108881907712/photo/1
http://twitter.com/hseongeon/status/410214156785029120/photo/1

In most iOS development cases, turnaround effect appears on cells by selecting themselves.
As you can see in my screenshots, however, sometimes the effect make a view's background color and text color what I don't want to be. (like badgeView in my screenshots)
I'd like not to change my badgeView's color when cells are selected.
How to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property `selectionStyle` on your cell to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`. This will prevent any calls to `setSelected` or `setHighlighted` on your cell.

Comment: I'd like to prevent badgeView's turnaround effect, but need cell selection and highlight.